# Any dangers with realloc?

Tags: realloc

Specifically:

1. what happens if I re-alloc an account but i forget to transfer enough lamports to make the account rent-exempt?
2. is it possible to make an account smaller?
3. The following note in the realloc [documentation](https://docs.rs/solana-program/latest/src/solana_program/account_info.rs.html#147-182) was confusing:

```
    /// This method makes assumptions about the layout and location of memory
    /// referenced by `AccountInfo` fields. It should only be called for
    /// instances of `AccountInfo` that were created by the runtime and received
    /// in the `process_instruction` entrypoint of a program.
```

I'm confused how it's even possible to call re-alloc without always satisfying these constraints.

Answer (score 2):

1. The transaction will fail if there's not enough lamports for the account to be rent-exempt.
2. Yes, you can make an account smaller.
3. This means that you should only use `realloc` in an on-chain program.  If you use it off-chain, it will cause a segfault because of the unsafe code that it performs.  Feel free to read the source code! https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/1fbd818647e7e87b9c706ddb26a28572d19a44c8/sdk/program/src/account_info.rs#L147